# How to set classpath on Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, talend, apache-httpcomponents

I've created a routine that depends on [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/), so I've downloaded the jar files and added those files to the Build Path.

I've set up both *Classpath Variables* and *User Libraries* under *Java\Build Path*, but it still doesn't work.

My code compile without any errors, but it fails to run with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy
    at routines.downloadXls.start(downloadXls.java:10)
[...]
```

The piece of Java code is the following, it runs with Eclipse:

```
private CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient() {
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpCtx.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, store);
        return builder.setRedirectStrategy(LaxRedirectStrategy.INSTANCE).build();
    }
```

I've already seen a [similar question on talend community](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/How-to-setup-classpath-in-Talend-Project-settings/td-p/33575), but it didn't help me.

Any suggestion, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your jar(s) in your Talend job using `tLibraryLoad` component (one per jar).

```
tLibraryLoad
        |
OnSubjobOk
        |
Code using apache components
```

When you build your job, the jars will be bundled with it and added to your classpath (in .bat and .sh launchers).
I noticed you're setting a cookie in your code, maybe if you give more detail about your requirement I can recommend a solution using dedicated Talend components, as it's best to use native components whenever possible (or you can ask a separate question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But I also need to set the `Classpath Variables `and the `User Libraries` under `Java\Build Path`? Or adding every jar file with `tLibraryLoad` is enough? Thanks

Comment: PS: I have to make 2 http post request (login and download) sharing cookies and session, and it seems not work with `tHttpRequest`.

Comment: Adding all the jars you need with `tLibraryLoad` is enough. Those settings you mention are inherited from Eclipse and are used by Talend itself afaik

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to issue a login request and use the cookie sent by the server to issue another request; here's a quick example I did to get the cookie from a response (Set-cookie header) : https://imgur.com/a/N0QSk
Feel free to ask a question about this, and I'll be happy to give it a try.